# How to get the value of data attribute using JQuery in asp.net core?

Tags: java, jquery, asp.net-core, .net-core

I want to get the value of the custom attribute by jquery.
I use this code to do that but in console it show "undefined":

```
var correct = $("div").data("correct");
```

this is the html:

```
<div data-correct="@classCorrect.Answer">....</div>
```

also, I used "attr" to do that but that was the same too and shows "undefined".
And I don't want to use "id" for the selector.
I want it to show 3 as it is in "@classCorrect.Answer".

Comment: when your jquery code gets run ? is that div exist in your dom or not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are serverl divs with the `data-correct` attribute, you should give them the same `class` or `name`

Such as:

```
<div class="test" data-correct="1">A</div>
<div class="test" data-correct="2">B</div>
<div class="test" data-correct="3">C</div>
```

And when you use the class or name selector, the result is an array of these elements, you should traverse it to get each element then get its attribute value.

```
$(function () {
    var datalist = $(".test");
    $.each(datalist, function (i,value) {
        console.log($(value).data('correct'));
    })
})
```

Comment: Thank you that's right.but how should I traverse it?It shows me an array of values for the data-attribute.

Comment: Use the jquery `each` function like that in my answer.

Comment: Thank's a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

use `.data()` if you use newer jQuery >= 1.4.3 and the part after data- must be lowercase, e.g. data-idNum will not work, but data-idnum will.

Use `attr`:

```
var correct =  $("div").attr('data-correct');
```

Answer (score 1):

I am sure that you have several divs in your html so you have to assign id to your div at first:

```
<div id="correctAnswer" data-correct="@classCorrect.Answer">....</div>
```

after this you can get data attribute value using .attr:

```
var correct =  $('#correctAnswer').attr('data-correct');
```

or if you use newer jQuery >= 1.4.3  you can try .data

```
var correct =  $('#correctAnswer').data('correct');
```

Comment: yes I have several divs but I can't use Id because It's in foreach loop and I can't have the static Id.

Comment: You have to show the whole view then. Do you realize that you are waisting people time with the questions like this. People who really need help can' t get it because it is impossible to help everybody. You have to show your view and explain which div value you need  and what for. Maybe you don't need it all and there another ways to accomplish your task.

Comment: I said it in the question that I have a div and it's in foreach loop. so I have several divs. I'm new to jquery.